# Optimizing the Uploading of huge amount of records/data

Tags: php, postgresql, extjs

Team...I have a problem when it comes to uploading of 2500 to 4000 records of data, it takes time to wait or sometimes it times out in the server.

Im using ExtJS 3.4.0, PHP 5.5.31 and PostgreSQL for my application in our development server.

My application has 3 tabs, the first tab is the **Uploading** tab, in which i will select a template (in a excel form **xlsx**) and upload its contents. The other tabs are just used for viewing and downloading the template. The main focus is the uploading tab.

In my PHP code, loops the records (based on the max rows in the excel)

- it has validations to check each record being looped
- it checks if the data record exist in the table then update that data, if not then insert new record

The problem here is that, it takes time like 20 to 25 minutes...is there a way to optimize this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: php is a scripting language and gets interpreted. Also the Excel support is not the best. maybe you can offload the work to a native c programm.

Comment: im not really in to c program @recycler :( need to optimized this...fak X_X

Comment: `it checks if the data record exist in the table then update that data, if not then insert new record`. That smells like you are doing three round-trips to the database *per record*. You don't need to. You can do it in one operation. Or better: insert *all* the records into a temp table, and update/insert from there; all inside the database.

Comment: You can definitely speed the process up by factor of ten or more if you use less queries per record, and by another factor of ten or more if you switch to a STORED PROCEDURE and let the database do everything. I would estimate that you can get down to below 5 seconds. For a better estimate, you have to show us your code.

Comment: what i did guys is that, in the looping part, it validates each data record, each record will be stored in an array...after the validation (outside the loop) it will insert in just one shot insert query and i guess it speeds up the process :)

Comment: @Alexander bro how can i apply this in a stored proc? :) i still have no idea how to do it...the excel file, loop records in the stored proc, etc.